# $c_{00}$ is a dense subset of $c_0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I would like to show that $c_{00}$ is a dense subset of $c_0$. I am not sure if I am overly simplifying the argument or even making the right argument for that matter.

proof:
Suppose that $x \in c_0$ is arbitrary. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x(n)| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Then we may observer that there exists $x_k \in c_{00}$ such that $x_k(n) = x(n)$ for all $n \leq N$ and $x_k(n) = 0$ for all $n > N$. Thus $\displaystyle \|x_k(n) - x(n)\|_\infty = \sup_{n}|x_k(n) - x(n)| < \epsilon$. Hence, $c_{00}$ is dense in $c_0$.

If anyone would be willing to give some feed back or some help if I need to fix anything I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for giving it a look over. I needed this result for another proof I had been working on and my Professor will not let me use any theorems or lemmas unless I prove them haha. I found that many proofs refer to this property, but I could not find it proven anywhere.